# How do I combine integers, to save gas on transaction data and storage?

Tags: gas, storage, gas-estimate, bytes, bytes32

For example, I have two integers: one is uint128, another is uint64. I want to store those two integers by converting them to bytes24. And when I use them, parse the bytes24 to uint128 and uint64.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Storage Cost**

Combining data from variables smaller than 32 bytes before storing is a good idea! `SSTORE` is very expensive at 20 kilogas per EVM word (32 bytes). Luckily, Solidity will do this for you under the hood if you compile with `solc --optimize`. See the "More Optimization" section of this [article on the EVM](https://medium.com/@hayeah/diving-into-the-ethereum-vm-6e8d5d2f3c30) for how that works. Might as well let the compiler do the work for you.

**Transaction Data Cost**

Sending in the parameters separately has its own gas cost. This shouldn't be top of your list of concerns, however: it only costs 68 gas per nonzero byte. That sounds like a lot for a full 32-byte uint, but if you are passing smaller values, they will have a lot of zeros (only priced at 4 gas per byte).

It turns out that you would only save 128 gas in transaction data costs by combining the fields, because you're only reducing the number of zeros you send, which are cheap. That saved gas does not even include the added cost of splitting the data again in Solidity. This is clearly not worth the effort, and probably has a net negative effect on gas costs.

Without combining the fields:

```
fieldA = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
fieldB = 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

transaction non-zero bytes = (128 + 64) / 8 = 24
transaction zero bytes = (128 + 192) / 8 = 40
gas cost for parameters = 68 * 24 + 4 * 40 = 1792
```

With combining the fields:

```
fieldC = 0x0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

transaction non-zero bytes = (128 + 64) / 8 = 24
transaction zero bytes = 64 / 8 = 8
gas cost for parameters = 68 * 24 + 4 * 8 = 1664
```

Comment: As my understanding,one param is cheaper than two params ?

Comment: Got it, I added a section about the gas cost of sending parameters in a transaction. Please accept if this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks so much,i understand.I do many test,now i decide to save the two parameters into a struct.